# Regex match specific URI

Tags: regex, rest, uri

Need to capture 3 elements from the requested URI.

A valid format of the URI would be as follows:

```
/users/{id}.{size}.{type}
```

Whereas id and size can be digits. And type can only be 'jpg' or 'png'.

The twist is that the size is optional. Hence the other format of the URI would be:

```
/users/{id}.{type}
```

Valid examples are as follows:

```
/users/123.100.jpg
/users/123.100.png
/users/123.jpg
/users/123.png
```

Invalid examples are as follows:

```
/users/asd.jpg
/users/123.tiff
/users/123..jpg
/users/123..100..jpg
/users/123..100.jpg
/users/123.100
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex. It extracts the `id, size and type`

First, this regex validates that the url matches your valid pattern.

```
\/users\/(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?\.(jpg|png)
```

- Id: `(?<=/)\d+`
- size: `(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)`. Assumes that the url is constructed in a valid manner.
- type: `.*(jpg|png)`

Comment: I tried it here http://www.rubular.com/r/3cVPEHOmTr and the problem is that it captures the {size} group with '.' whereas '.' should not be included!

Comment: @Peymankh which regex? The initial one or the size specific one?

Comment: The initial one. If you click on the link you'll find the regex.

Comment: What about this? /users/(\d+)\.?(\d+)?\.(?i)(jpg|png)

Answer (score 1):

this regex should do the validation for you:

```
/users/(\d+\.){1,2}(jpg|png)
```

example see here: http://regexr.com?33vba

Comment: @Kata I didn't get you. did you click the link in my answer and see the example? what did you mean 1 or 2 characters??